# Undefine getters error while page rendered in vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, getter

This Is My Global state and  shared component I set and defined getters here

```
export default {
    getters: {
    loading(state) {
      return state.loading;
    },
    statusMessage(state) {
      return state.statusMessage;
    },
  },
}
```

The store export shared modules here

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import shared from './shared/index.js'


Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
 
  modules:{
    shared: shared,

  }
});
```

The registration template component here i want to access loading and error message but actually the problem of mine is when the page rendering I found this errors in console

```
in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined"

found in

---> <Registrations> at src/views/Registrations.vue
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

```
 computed: {

    loading (){
      return this.$store.getters.loading
    },
    error(){
      return this.$store.getters.statusMessage
    }
  }
```

getters are defined above as I Shown and export as well but I not able to find the reason what's the reason and problem there!!! help me If You can

Answer (score 0):

try `this.$store.shared.getters.loading` - because you are using a module getter